Understand example of LU decomposition with partial pivots
The example matrix is
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 20 & 400 \\
1 & 30 & 900 \\
1 & 40 & 1600 
\end{bmatrix}
In the first step, they compute using previously derived equations:
$$
u_{11} = a_{11} = 1 \\
l_{21} = a_{21}/u_{11} = 1 \\
l_{31} = a_{31}/u_{11} = 1
$$
The conclusion is that all "potential pivots have magnitude $1$", so we don't need to perform any permutations.
In the next step,
$$
u_{12} = a_{12} = 20 \\
u_{22} = a_{22} - l_{21}u_{12} = 10 \\
u_{22}l_{32} = a_{32} - l_{31}u_{12} = 20 \\
$$
And here we need to swap rows 2 and 3, since $10 < 20$.

I'm OK with the derived equations that are used to compute the elements of $L, U$ respectively.
I don't understand why in the second step we care about $u_{22}l_{32}$? I thought the point about applying permutations to the matrix was to ensure the pivots are always largest in magnitude and are not zero, and the pivots are $u_{ii}$, the diagonals of $U$. Why are we looking then at $u_{22}l_{32}$?
Similarly, what is meant with "potential pivots"?

thanks @Moo the example and the linked PDF are useful to understand what's going on. In particular in section 4 they show the sequence how columns are scanned for potential pivots.

We are given
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 20 & 400 \\
1 & 30 & 900 \\
1 & 40 & 1600 
\end{bmatrix}$$
We want to find the LU decomposition with partial pivoting using Section $4$, to determine $PA = LU$, where $P$ is the associated permutation matrix.
We write
$$\tag 1 LU = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
l_{21} & 1 & 0 \\
l_{31} & l_{32} & 1 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
u_{11} & u_{12} & u_{13} \\
0 & u_{22} & u_{23} \\
0 & 0 & u_{33} 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 20 & 400 \\
1 & 30 & 900 \\
1 & 40 & 1600 
\end{bmatrix} = A$$
Following the notes, since every potential pivot in the first column is $1$, there is no need to permute any rows.
We just want to eliminate the $1$ in rows two and three.
We can write $R_2: -1 R_1 + R_2 = (0, 10, 500)$ and $R_3: - 1 R_1 + R_3 = (0, 20, 1200)$
To align with the notes, we will insert these values and a fake $P_1$ (no permutation of rows to keep $P's$ and $L's$ balanced) into $(1)$
$$L_1 P_1 A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 20 & 400 \\
1 & 30 & 900 \\
1 & 40 & 1600 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 20 & 400 \\
 0 & 10 & 500 \\
 0 & 20 & 1200 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now if we look at the second column of the last two rows, we see that the third row is larger than the second $( 30 \gt 20)$, so we want to permute the second and third row.
This gives
$$P_2 =  \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Inserting this into the mix
$$P_2 L_1 P_1 A = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 20 & 400 \\
 0 & 20 & 1200 \\
 0 & 10 & 500 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
We now write $R_3: -1/2 R_2 + R_3 = (0, -100)$ and can fill in the value of $l_{32}$ as
$$L_2 A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1/2 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 20 & 400 \\
 0 & 20 & 1200 \\
 0 & 10 & 500 \\
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 20 & 400 \\
 0 & 20 & 1200 \\
 0 & 0 & -100 \\
\end{bmatrix} = U
$$
Now, we have
$$L = (L_2P_2L_1P_1)^{-1} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & \frac{1}{2} & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Verify $PA = LU$.
